# Creating a function to print the exponents without using **

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm tasked with writing a function in Python 3 to essentially recreate the ** command for the powers of 2, given a number (eg- if n = 10, print out 1,2,4...1024).

I can't use any predefined imports or functions (math.pow).

My thought process would be to use a for loop and then have each following iteration to multiply by 2 to recreate this:

- 2^0 = 1
- 2^1 = 2 * 1 (from last line)
- 2^2 = 2 * 2 (from last line)
- 2^3 = 2 * (2*2) (from last line)
- 2^4 = 2* (2^3) (from last line)

First I figured I would  have a for loop, just print 2, n number of times:

```
n = 5
for i in range of (n+1)
    print(2)
```

and the output would just be

- (how to deal with this empty space?), 2 2 2 2 2

but I can't do much with this other than realize that the i in the for loop corresponds to the exponent of 2**i.

Then I thought I would use the *= multiplication assignment to first print (2) but then also multiply it by the previous iteration to store it as a new value and print out the variables as they get overwritten but I wasn't sure how to configure my for loop to do such a thing.

Any tips on which method would be best to start tackling this question? I'm at a loss.

Comment: use bit shift operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we all know, pow is just repeated multiplication.

So, we can create a loop that on every iteration it'll multiply a variable (we'll declare a variable that his starting value is 1) by 2.

Example code:

```
powers = 1 # Declare variable.
for pow in range(10): # Set a loop for range(10).
    print(powers) # Print the variable.
    powers *= 2 # Power it by 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

Given indices are just repeated multiplication, you could use the for loop to progressively multiply it.

Something like:

```py
n = 5
runningPower = 1
for i in range(n + 1):
  runningPower *= 2
  print(runningPower)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *print* them, this looks like a good way to start learning the intricacies of Python, specifically the use of generators:

```
def twoPower(count):
    val = 1
    for _ in range(count):
        yield val
        val = val * 2
```

You can construct a list with this generator simply by using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [_ for _ in twoPower(5)]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

And, of course, you can make that more readable by turning them into strings and joining them (use `"\n"` rather than `" "`, if you want each number on a separate line):

```
>>> print(" ".join([str(_) for _ in twoPower(5)]))
1 2 4 8 16
```

---

If instead you want a *function* that will give you the power (at least for non-negative integral exponents), you can just use recursion, knowing that the expression `np` is:

- `n * np-1` where `p` is greater than zero; or
- `1` where `p` is equal to zero.

That means the function could be as simple as that below:

```
def pwr(n, p):
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    return n * pwr(n, p - 1)

# Test harness.

for n1 in range(-2, 4):
    for n2 in range(0, 4):
        print(f"{n1:3} ** {n2:3} = {pwr(n1, n2):3}")
```

Running that code gives you the desired results:

```
 -2 **   0 =   1
 -2 **   1 =  -2
 -2 **   2 =   4
 -2 **   3 =  -8
 -1 **   0 =   1
 -1 **   1 =  -1
 -1 **   2 =   1
 -1 **   3 =  -1
  0 **   0 =   1
  0 **   1 =   0
  0 **   2 =   0
  0 **   3 =   0
  1 **   0 =   1
  1 **   1 =   1
  1 **   2 =   1
  1 **   3 =   1
  2 **   0 =   1
  2 **   1 =   2
  2 **   2 =   4
  2 **   3 =   8
  3 **   0 =   1
  3 **   1 =   3
  3 **   2 =   9
  3 **   3 =  27
```

Now that won't handle negative exponents, but you could fix that with:

```
def pwr(n, p):
    if p < 0:
        return 1 / pwr(n, -p)
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    return n * pwr(n, p - 1)
```

It also won't handle non-integral exponents but that's a lot more difficult, so I prefer to reject them out of hand:

```
def pwr(n, p):
    if str(type(p)) != "<class 'int'>":
        raise Exception("Non-integral power")
    if p < 0:
        return 1 / pwr(n, -p)
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    return n * pwr(n, p - 1)
```